# I am trying to retrieve the content from an Excel using Python. I am getting Investment undefined error

Tags: python

```
import xlrd
import os
class datafromexcel:

  def  __init__(self) -> None:
      
    rootPath = os.getcwd()
    
    loc = (rootPath+"Investment.xlsx"); 
    
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
    list = [];  
    for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
            #print(sheet.cell_value(i, 0),sheet.cell_value(i, 1)) 
            list.append(Investment(sheet.cell_value(i, 0),sheet.cell_value(i, 1)));
    print("Successfully retrieved all excel data");
```

Comment: What is `Investment` - you seem to be trying to use an Investment class that doesn't seem defined anywhere, hence the undefined error

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Pandas library and read your excel file with it

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel('EXCEL_FILE.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

for more details: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give a try with Pandas.